# Order in startup application preferences

Tags: 14.04, startup, startup-applications

I have two tasks in startup application preferences:
1. Start Dropbox
2. Mount partition for dropbox folder

I need first of all do job #2 (mount partition) and only then Start Dropbox. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delay one of the startup applications by adding `-p 10` after their entry in the list. This will cause a 10 second delay before it starts. Change the value to get the result you need.