# How to change the order of execution of services at startup?

Tags: 14.04, startup, services, init.d

I have some services in my init.d folder for e.g. hdfs, zookeeper, elasticsearch, hbase and so on.

Now, I have added all those services to startup by doing the `update-rc.d 'service' defaults` command. As we know, hbase can't run if hdfs and zookeeper are not started. So I want to start hdfs first, then zookeeper and then finally hbase.

how do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order in startup application preferences](http://askubuntu.com/questions/647490/order-in-startup-application-preferences)

Comment: @Parto - It still does not answer my question properly. I don't want to add delays. I want to specify an order. So its not a duplicate.

Comment: Then this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49274/how-to-change-the-order-of-startup-applications

Comment: You should consider migrating these from sysv init scripts to Upstart services. Then you can say: `start on started hdfs` for  zookeeper and `start on started zookeeper` for hbase, etc.

Comment: @muru - Yeah. Will consider that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it by `update-rc.d 'service' defaults number` where the number is an integer and the lesser the sequence number, the higher the service in the queue i.e it will be executed before other services with a greater sequence number.

The above command will give the same priority for starting as well as killing the service. You can fine tune it further.

So if you have a service which has a lot of dependencies, you can give it a large sequence number to ensure that all of its dependiencies have booted up before it starts itself.

Answer (score 3):

update-rc.d(8) enables or disables services, while the ordering of services is handled by insserv(8), and can be customized by editing the LSB header of the service and setting/adding:

```
Required-Start: $all
```

In oldest versions, i can do something like this to determine the order:

```
update-rc.d myservice start 95 2 3 4 5 . stop 70 0 1 6 .
```

But after Ubuntu 14, i tried this Ubuntu 16.04 (4.4.0-31-generic):

```
update-rc.d myservice defaults 95 70
```

And doesn't work, always creates the order defined in the header:

```
 sudo find /etc/ -name ???myservice | sort
/etc/rc0.d/K01myservice
/etc/rc1.d/K01myservice
/etc/rc2.d/S03myservice
/etc/rc3.d/S03myservice
/etc/rc4.d/S03myservice
/etc/rc5.d/S03myservice
/etc/rc6.d/K01myservice
```

Also al try:

```
update-rc.d myservice defaults any_text_wath_you_want lalala
```

Ands seems like ignores all the text after "defaults". I don´t know wath it do when my installation order, I do not think that orders previously installed services.