# Ubuntu 18.04 change startup service order

Tags: startup, services

My problem is
ics-dhcpserver starts before network services so dhcp cannot find interface
i can swap/change order for startup services?

Regards,
Aki

Comment: this is similar to your question https://askubuntu.com/questions/753922/how-to-change-the-order-of-execution-of-services-at-startup

Comment: Which systemd target is `ics-dhcpserver` linked to?  Do you know how to link the service to a later target during the boot sequence? Or are you asking how to do that?

Comment: See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097111/how-do-i-change-the-order-in-which-systemd-services-are-started-up