# How do I change the order in which systemd services are started up

Tags: server, systemd, nginx, dnsmasq

Ubuntu 18.04 server on my home network
I'm running:

- dnsmasq for DHCP and DNS
- nginx as a reverse proxy to some web applications (running on localhost and on other hosts)

The nginx reverse proxy config uses hostnames, eg:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://nas.mydomain.com:8080;
```

However, when rebooting the server, nginx tries to start up but fails due to not being able to resolve the hostnames in its config. If I start nginx up manually after boot, it starts up without error.

This leads me to believe that nginx is starting before dnsmasq is available to resolve the hostnames.

Is there a way to force nginx to start after dnsmasq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Systemd tries to start multiple services in parallel, unless you tell it not do.  If you have dependencies, you need to use directives like After in the services definition file.

In this case, if you need to start the nginx service after the dnsmasq service is running, you can add

```
After=dnsmasq.service
```

into the nginx.service file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i found this particular answer quite helpful. I copied it from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/start-a-service-only-after-mysql-has-entered-active-running-state

Generally, to declare a strict dependency, you will want both After and Requires:

```
[Unit]
Description=My application 
After=mysqld.service
Requires=mysqld.service
```

If for some reason you’re still not have the expected behavior, another option would be to use a script in ExecStartPre that blocks until it can connect to the database. wait-for-it is a useful tool for this: https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

For more info on working with systemd unit files, check out:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files